# OpenMP SIMD reduction in array: "error: reduction variable must be shared on entry to this OpenMP pragma"

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, simd

I am trying to compute the average value over adjacent elements within a matrix, but am stuck getting OpenMP's vectorization to work. As I understand the second nested for-loop, the `reduction` clause should ensure that no race conditions occur when writing to elements of `next`. However, when compiling the code (I tried auto-vectorization with both GCC GCC 7.3.0 and ICC and OpenMP > 4.5) I get the report: "error: reduction variable "next" must be shared on entry to this OpenMP pragma". Why does this occur when variables are shared by default? How can I fix this issue since adding `shared(next)` does not seem to help?

```c
// CODE ABOVE (...)
size_t const width = 100;
size_t const height = 100;
float * restrict next = malloc(sizeof(float)*width*height);

// INITIALIZATION OF 'next' (this works fine)
#pragma omp for simd collapse(2) 
  for(size_t j = 1; j < height-1; j++)
    for(size_t i = 1; i < width-1; i++)
      next[j*width+i] = 0.0f; 

// COMPUTE AVERAGE FOR INNER ELEMENTS
#pragma omp for simd collapse(4) reduction(+:next[0:width*height]) 
for(size_t j = 1; j < height-1; ++j){
  for(size_t i = 1; i < width-1; ++i){
    // compute average over adjacent elements
    for(size_t _j = 0; _j < 3; _j++) {
      for(size_t _i = 0; _i < 3; _i++) {
          next[j*width + i] += (1.0 / 9.0) * next[(j-1 +_j)*width + (i-1 + _i)]; 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that GCC 7.3.0 does not support

```
#pragma omp for simd collapse(4) reduction(+:next[0:width*height])
```

the use of `reduction` of array sections in this context.

This function is support by [GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp) forwards:

> Since GCC 9, there is initial OpenMP 5 support (essentially C/C++,
> only). GCC 10 added some more features, mainly for C/C++ but also for
> Fortran.