# Data race in parallelized nested loop

Tags: c, openmp, simd, data-race

I have a triple nested loop that I would like to parallelize, however, I am getting a data race issue. I am pretty sure that I need to use a reduction somehow, but I don't quite know how.

This is the loop in question:

```c
#pragma omp parallel for simd collapse(3)
    for (uint64 u = 0; u < nu; ++u) {
        for (uint64 e = 0; e < ne; ++e) {
            for (uint64 v = 0; v < nv; ++v) {
                uAT[u][e] += _uT[u][e][v] * wA[e][v];
            }
        }
    }
```

Could someone explain to me, why this causes a data race? I would really like to understand this, so that I don't run into these issues in the future. Also, can this loop be parallelized at all? If so, how?

EDIT: How do I know that there is a data race?

What this loop should accomplish (and it does in serial) is to compute the element average of a function in a Discontinuous Galerkin frame work. When I run the code a bunch of times, sometimes I get different results, eventhough it should always produce the same results. The resulting wrong values are always smaller than what the should be, which is why I assume that some values are not being added. Maybe this picture explains it better: The average in the third cell is obviously wrong (too small).
[image: The average in the third cell is obviously wrong (too small).]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the actual issues you get? Why do you think they are because of a data-race?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

##### Original answer concerning multi-threading, not SIMD

By using the `collapse(3)` clause, the whole iteration space of `nu * ne * nv` iterations is distributed among threads. This means that for any combination of `u` and `e`, the `v` loop could be distributed among multiple threads as well. These can then access the same element `uAT[u][e]` in parallel, which is the data race.

As long as `nu * ne` is much bigger than the number of CPU cores that you work on, the easiest solution is to instead use `collapse(2)`. As there can be inefficient implementations of `collapse` (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72981522/10107454)), you might even want to leave it away completely depending on `nu` being big enough.

If you really need the parallelism from all three loops to efficiently use your hardware, you can use either `reduction(+: uAT[0:nu][0:ne])` (add it into your existing pragma) or put a `#pragma omp atomic update` in front of `uAT[u][e] += ...;`. Which of these options is faster should be benchmarked. The `reduction` clause will use a lot more memory due to every thread getting its own private copy of the whole memory addressed through `uAT`. On the other hand the `atomic update` could in the worst case sequentialize part of your parallel work and give worse performance than using `collapse(2)`.

##### Edit 1: SIMD

I just saw that you are also concerned with SIMD instead of just multi-threading. My original answer is about the latter. For SIMD I would first take a look at your compilers output without any OpenMP directives (e.g. on [Compiler Explorer](https://c.godbolt.org/)). If your compiler (with optimization and information on the target processor architecture) does already use SIMD instructions, you might not need to use OpenMP in the first place.

If you still want to use OpenMP for vectorizing your loops, leaving away the `collapse` clause and putting the pragma in front of the second loop would be my first ansatz. Leaving it in front of the first loop with `collapse(2)` might also work. Even a `reduction` should work but seems unnecessary complex in this context, as I would expect there to be enough parallelism in `nu` or `nu * ne` to fill your SIMD lanes. I have never used array reduction like described below in the SIMD context, so I'm not quite sure what it would do (i.e. allocating an array for each SIMD lane doesn't seem realistic), or if it even is part of the OpenMP standard (depends on the version of the standard, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66713763/10107454)).

The way your code is written right now, the description of the data race for multi-threading technically still applies, I think. I'm not sure though if your code causes (efficient) vectorization at all, so the compiled binary might not have the data race (it might not be vectorized at all).

##### Edit 2: Threading + SIMD

I benchmarked a few versions of this loop nest for `nu = 4`, `nv = 128` and `ne` between `1024` and `524288` (2^19). My benchmarking was done using google-benchmark (i.e. C++ instead of C, shouldn't matter here, I would think) with gcc 11.3 (always using `-march=native -mtune=native`, i.e. for portable performance this might not be helpful). I made sure to initialize all data in parallel (first touch policy) to avoid bad NUMA effects. I slightly modified the problem/code to use contiguous memory and do the multi-dimensional indexing manually. As OP's code didn't show the data type, I used `float`.

The three best versions I will share here are all three performing relatively similar. So depending on the hardware architecture there might be differences in which one is the best. For me the version inspired by Peter Cordes comments below this answer performed best:

```c
#pragma omp parallel for
for (uint64_t e = 0UL; e < ne; ++e) {
  // In the future we will get `#pragma omp unroll partial(4)`.
  // The unrolling might actually not be necessary (or even a pessimization).
  // So maybe leave it to the compiler.
  #pragma GCC unroll 4
  for (uint64_t u = 0UL; u < nu; ++u) {
    float temp = 0.0f;
    #pragma omp simd reduction(+ : temp)
    for (uint64_t v = 0UL; v < nv; ++v) {
      temp += uT[(u * ne + e) * nv + v] * wA[e * nv + v];
    }
    uAT[u * ne + e] += temp;
  }
}
```

One could also have a `float temp[nu];` and put the unrolled `u` loop inside the `v` loop to get even nearer to Peter Cordes' description, but then on would have to use an array reduction as described above. These array reductions consistently caused stack overflows for me, so I settled on this version which depends on `nv` being small enough that `wA` can still be cached between `u` iterations.

This second version just differs in the `u` loop staying on the outside:

```c
#pragma omp parallel
for (uint64_t u = 0UL; u < nu; ++u) {
  #pragma omp for
  for (uint64_t e = 0UL; e < ne; ++e) {
    float temp = 0.0f;
    #pragma omp simd reduction(+ : temp)
    for (uint64_t v = 0UL; v < nv; ++v) {
      temp += uT[(u * ne + e) * nv + v] * wA[e * nv + v];
    }
    uAT[u * ne + e] += temp;
  }
}
```

The third version uses `collapse(2)`:

```c
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for (uint64_t u = 0UL; u < nu; ++u) {
  for (uint64_t e = 0UL; e < ne; ++e) {
    float temp = 0.0f;
    #pragma omp simd reduction(+ : temp)
    for (uint64_t v = 0UL; v < nv; ++v) {
      temp += uT[(u * ne + e) * nv + v] * wA[e * nv + v];
    }
    uAT[u * ne + e] += temp;
  }
}
```

##### TL;DR:

I think the most important points can be seen in all three versions:

- `#pragma omp parallel for simd` is nice for big simple loops. If you have a loop nest, you probably should split the pragma up.
- Use `simd` on a loop which accesses contiguous elements in contiguous iterations.
- By respecting the first two points, you don't need the possibly expensive array reduction.
- By using a temporary (i.e. register) for the reduction instead of writing back to memory, you make using OpenMP easier and probably have better performance in serial code as well. Due to floating point non-associativity, this optimization can't be done by most compilers without allowing it via e.g. `-ffast-math` (gcc).
- Most compilers can not vectorize the reduction on their own for the same reason.
- Details like Using `collapse` or the the order of the `e` and the `u` loop are smaller optimizations which are not as important as long as you provide enough parallelism. I.e. don't parallelize over just `u` if `nu` is small (as the question author wrote below this answer).

Comment: I do not think that using `collapse(3)` clause would result in a faster code than using `collapse(2)` or using no collapse at all.

Comment: @Laci Well, e.g. for a `nu = nv = ne = 8` loop nest, I could imagine it. But I just saw that the question concerns SIMD, not multithreading, so my answer isn't quite on-topic right now either.

Comment: Well, in the case of  `nu = nv = ne = 8` no parallelism is needed :-)  The OP's question does include multithreading `#pragma omp parallel for  ...` and simd.

Comment: As far as I understood, `#pragma omp parallel for simd` does both, multi-threading and SIMD instructions. In this case I am more interested in the multi-threading issue. `nu` is the number of unknowns of the system, so usually something between 1 and 5. `ne` is the number of elements, this is the biggest one of the loops. Based on your answer I just parallelised the `ne` loop, leaving away the collapse. This seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Without any `#pragma omp`, if the arrays are floating point and you didn't use `-ffast-math`, a compiler couldn't vectorize the inner loop reduction (dot product).  It would be forced to do the operations in source order, because FP math is not strictly associative.  It could sum into multiple `uAT[u][e]` in parallel (after SIMD shuffling), but that would be inefficient.  So you do really want to tell the compiler it can vectorize over `v`. (@koipond)

Comment: Getting it to unroll over `u` might also help, using each vector of `wA[e][v + 0..3]` with a couple different  `_uT[u + 1][e][v + 0..3]` vectors.  Unfortunately those are the farthest away and aren't contiguous when storing into `uAT[u][e]`, but that looks like the only chance to reduce computational intensity (reuse data multiple times while it's hot in registers or cache).  Unlike a normal matmul, one input does have O(n^3) data, except it's a different size in each dimension.  Oh, apparently `nu` is typically tiny small, so yeah maybe <=5 input streams from there plus one from `wA` is good.

Comment: @koipond: parallelizing over `e` looks appropriate.  If `nv` is huge (too big for `wA[e][0..nv-1]` to fit in L1d or maybe L2 cache size), and `nu` is higher than you have a specialized version for, you might use a cache-blocked version that doesn't cover the whole range of `v`s before doing the early `v`s again with the other `u`.

Comment: Also worth considering doing multiple `e`s at once in the inner loop.  (Is that what OMP `collapse()` does?)  That way you have some contiguous stores to do with `uAT`.  Anyway, if I was vectorizing this by hand, that's what I'd be thinking about.  Having 5 versions of the loop (for each common `nu`) that you dispatch to is probably helpful.  Re: multiple input streams in an inner loop: see [For-loop efficiency: merging loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51021262) - modern CPUs are generally fine with at least 6.

Comment: I expanded on my answer @koipond.

Comment: @PeterCordes No, `collapse` just lets you parallelize over the full iterations space of multiple nested loops.